# Nested JSON PHP decode

Tags: php, json

I have the following Json file

```
{
    "username”: “userabc”,
    “locations”: [
        {
            “locationId": "2123",
            “locationName": "Test Site",
            “setupDate”: "0000-00-00",
            “dataType”: {
                “book”: [
                    {
                        “bookId": “1257245",
                        “information”: “Infotag 181”,
                        “addedDate": "0000-00-00 00:00:00"
                    },
                    {
                        “bookId": “4257245",
                        “information”: “Infotag 11”,
                        “addedDate": "0000-00-00 00:00:00"
                    },
                    {
                        “bookId": “2227242”,
                        “information”: “Infotag 181”,
                        “addedDate": "0000-00-00 00:00:00"
                    }
                ],
                “tape”: [
                    {
                        “tapeId": “1220”,
                        “information”: “Infotag 181”,
                        “addedDate": "0000-00-00 00:00:00"
                    },
                    {
                        “tapeId": “1320”,
                        “information”: “Infotag 181”,
                        “addedDate": "0000-00-00 00:00:00"
                    }
                ],
                “record”: [
                    {
                        “recordId": “a21322”,
                        “information”: “Infotag 181”,
                        “addedDate": "0000-00-00 00:00:00"
                    },
                    {
                        “recordId": “b213222”,
                        “information”: “Infotag 181”,
                        “addedDate": "0000-00-00 00:00:00"
                    }
                ],
                "virtual": [
                    {
                        “virtId": "2123",
                        “information”: "57235",
                        “addedDate”: "0000-00-00 00:00:00",

                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I'm currently trying to access the nested part of (to count the number of bookIDs). I have done the following, can print the locationName but I am unable to print the bookId, I'm not sure where I'm going wrong.

```
$obj = json_decode($json,true);

foreach($obj['locations'] as $chunk) {
  $locName = $chunk['locationName'];
  echo $locName;
}
```

This is the part I am having problems with, I am not able to see any results?

```
foreach($obj['locations']['book'] as $chunk) {
  $bkId = $chunk['bookId'];
  echo $bkId;
}
```

Comment: So what have you tried? What part of that are you having difficulty with?

Comment: SO is not a **free coding resource** and we **dont work from specifications, not even good ones** you are expected to have tried something for yourself. If you have a specific problem with what you are trying to code then ask a question and we are more than willing to help

Comment: Read [the JSON pages of the PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.json.php)

Comment: Thanks for your comments I will look into it an try to come up with a better question.

Comment: Try to print_r() or vardump() the $chunk inside your loop to realize what you've actually got. You'll see its an object and you should probably access it using $chunk->locationName.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$obj['locations']` is a collection. You'll want to iterate over it with `foreach` or just access the first element using `$obj['locations'][0]`. I.e. you'd access `$obj['locations'][0]['books']`.

If you run your code with `error_reporting(0);` and `ini_set('display_errors', true);`, you will get a warning when you access a non-existing key of an array, so you would be told what's wrong here.